# Reference dynamic keyup fields (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have dynamically created column header, which can increase/decrease in size if a user adds/removes columns.

In the column header, I have a dynamically created keyup field.  I want to reference the values in these fields (though not save them a la a form)

What is the best way to reference these fields?

```
 <th *ngFor="let Col of Columns; let i=index">
    <input #columnInput[i] (keyup)="setColValues(columnInput[i].value,i)">
 </th>
```

It will not work using a reference variable (like above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular template syntax is not support arrays. But you may do it without **[i]**. And it's will works fine because template variable is limited in its scope (th)

```
<th *ngFor="let Col of Columns; let i=index">
    <input #columnInput (keyup)="setColValues(columnInput.value,i)">
 </th>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.